# Magento Pagination

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, pager

I am working on a Magento theme, so in the product list page I have featured products block and below it a normal product listing with pagination, however what I need, that's when the user click on the page2 in the pager I want to remove the featured block and also I want to increase the default page size of the pager result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create module with observer to solve this issue, 
update your catalog.xml (override the original one, don't edit the original one) this is a handle

```
<catalog_category_pager>
    <remove name="featured"/>
</catalog_category_pager>
```

observer function

```
public function hideFeatured(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $controller = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
    $request = $controller->getRequest();
    $pagerPage = $request->getParam('p');
    $update = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate();
    //Also we may check for order and sort variables in order to hide the block also 
    if($pagerPage > 1){
       $update->addHandle('catalog_category_pager');
    }    
}
```

config.xml of your module
    

    
        
            
                
                    
                        Yourmodule_Pager_Model_Observer
                        hideFeatured